# how to initialize the size of a two dimensional vector

Tags: c++, structure, stdvector

I am trying to initialize the size of a 2 dimensional vector with this way:

```
 vector<vector<int> >  a(10, vector<int>) ;
```

but when I compile it I get this error:expected primary-expression before ')' token

why? Which is the correct way to do it?

In my code this vector is defined inside a structure. I just realise that if I define it outside of the structure the problem disappears... but why? I need to define it in the struct

Comment: XY problem! What problem are you trying to solve? Also, this is obviously a C++ problem. This question was originally tagged with only the `stdvector` tag. Please, please, please add the appropriate language tag to future questions.

Comment: Can you explain, why simply `std::vector<std::vector<int>> a (10, std::vector<int> (10));` wouldn't work?

Comment: yes this works! but this creates a 10x10 vector if I understand well. I would like to initialize only 1 dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
class Inner : public vector<int> {
   public:
      Inner() : vector<int>(10) { };
};

class Outer : public vector<Inner> {
   public:
      Outer() vector<inner>(10) {  };
};
```

Then

```
 Outer a;
```

should work.

Comment: thank you Ed! But I would like a simpler way... In my code this vector is defined inside a structure which is used as value in a map...  So I am not sure if i can do  it with this way....

Comment: That's way more complicated than necessary.

Comment: You can as this creates two classes that you can use anywhere

Comment: Why is this complicated?

Comment: @EdHeal I said, that it's more complicated than necessary. Also, I've never been a fan of writing wrappers for everything (especially such simple constructs), since that obfuscates the code.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius  - That is a matter of opinion. I am of the opinion of naming things

Comment: @EdHeal When you develop alone, yes, naming things _may_ look nicer. But when you are trying to read the code written by other people, you often want to know what is the exact type of variable x, and that obfuscation via wrappers involves extra bit of work of finding that out. Especially if there are multiple, different kinds of wrappers.

Comment: This is a matter of opinion. It also does have the advantage of preventing people doing daft things - e.g. copying a list of points to a list of widths/heights of rectangles.

Comment: In my code this vector is defined inside a structure. I just realise that if I define it outside of the structure the problem disappears...

but why? I need to define it in the struct